# combobox in VB net community can not update

Tags: vb.net

I am Try to develop desktop APP, I have problem when update data using ComboBox, (there's no problem when insert data with combobox, error appear when updating data:

```
Try
                Call Koneksi()
                sql = "UPDATE tblpartner SET name ='" & Txtname.Text & "',group ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "',identityno ='" & txtidentityno.Text & "', NPWP ='" & txtNPWP.Text & "',address ='" & Txtaddress.Text & "', city='" & Txtcity.Text & "',province='" & Txtprovince.Text & "',postal ='" & Txtpostal.Text & "',area='" & Txtarea.Text & "',phone='" & Txtphone.Text & "',email ='" & Txtemail.Text & "',bank='" & Txtbank.Text & "',bankaccount='" & Txtbankaccount.Text & "' WHERE partnerID = '" & txtID.Text & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, db)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Changes have been saved in the database", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "System Confirmation")
                Call clear()
                Call Standby()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error: ", ex.Message)
            End Try
```

when update data message appear :
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "You have an error in your SQL sy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

when I remove the combobox update data no problem at all
please help n thanks

Comment: Use parameters to build your sql statement.

Comment: This is just one the many issues that the use of parameters addresses. Do it properly and this issue goes away and you're spared a bunch of others in the future, including the potential for your entire database to be deleted by a malicious user.

Comment: Now and in the future, you need to specify EXACTLY where an error occurs and, if you have issues with SQL code, you need to actually look at that SQL code for yourself and, if you still need help with it, show it to us. It's truly incredible how many people are told that their SQL is wrong and never even bother to look at that SQL to see what it contains.

Comment: All these warning about parameters are absolutely correct. Creating an sql command concatenating strings piece by piece is the perfect recipe for future disasters. Look at how a parameterized query [looks like](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=c5ec58c049e3647aJmltdHM9MTY2MTQwODc2MiZpZ3VpZD1mZDY5MmU5ZS1iMTczLTQ4MjMtODBjZC0zNTdhMWQ5ZTE5ZWUmaW5zaWQ9NTE1MA&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=ca2c0894-243e-11ed-87c5-f3430a6f2ee2&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9xdWVzdGlvbnMvNjUyOTc4L3BhcmFtZXRlcml6ZWQtcXVlcnktZm9yLW15c3FsLXdpdGgtYy1zaGFycA&ntb=1)

Comment: However your error is probably caused by the fieldname named _group_. This is a reserved word for MySql. If you have a field with that name then everytime you use it in a query you should add the backtick character around it (ALT+96)

Comment: @Steve very interesting! Didn't know it was called a backtick!

Comment: @AndrewMortimer backtick also curly opening quotes, backquote, grave accent. Confusing  to say the least https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick#:~:text=The%20backtick%20character%20represents%20curly%20opening%20quotes.%20For,an%20ASCII%20character%20wherever%20a%20number%20is%20expected.